# How to bind an object in a view to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This may be a dumb question but I'm kind of new with the razor. I'm trying to create a dynamic form. I have a list of object of fields and show them dynamically in my page. But, when I want to save the selected value of my field for a dropdown(example), I don't know how to save the object of my `foreach` to my model in the controller (I can save my value with no harm).

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var buildingBlock in buildingBlocks)
    {
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@buildingBlock.BuildingBlockTitle</h5>
                    @foreach (Test.Test.Models.BuildingBlockField buildingBlockField in buildingBlockFields)
                    {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
                        //I tried that but it's not working (Obviously :))
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => buildingBlockField)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[0].Values, buildingBlockField.OptionDetails, "Select Contract", new { @class = "selectpicker", multiple = "multiple" })
                    </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**BuildingBlockField:**

```
public class BuildingBlockField
{
    public int BuildingBlockFieldID{ get; set; }
    public int BuildingBlockID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem>? OptionDetails { get; set; }
    public string FieldTitle { get; set; }
    public FieldType Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsMultiple { get; set; }

    public int[] Values { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**model controller:**

```
public class ContractInformationsModel
{
    public List<BuildingBlockField> buildingBlockFields { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.BuildingBlocks = Models.BuildingBlock.getBuildingBlocks();
        ViewBag.BuildingBlockFields = Models.BuildingBlockField.getBuildingBlockFields();

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult generateWordContract(ContractInformationsModel contractInformations)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

I expect to find in my controller object `contractInformations` to find a list of buildingBlockFields with all the information and not only the value.

Thank you

Edit :

This seems to work but i have to do it for every property and hide then. Is there any other solution ?

```
                        @for (var i = 0; i < buildingBlockFields.Count(); i++){
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[i].BuildingBlockFieldID, new { Value = buildingBlockFields[i].BuildingBlockFieldID })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[i].FieldTitle, new { Value = buildingBlockFields[i].FieldTitle })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[i].Type, new { Value = buildingBlockFields[i].Type })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[0].Values, buildingBlockFields[i].OptionDetails, "Select Contract", new { @class = "selectpicker", multiple = "multiple" })
                        </div>
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing `ContractInformationsModel` model to your view, which has a list of type `BuildingBlockField`, your html should contain the building block field ID and a "counter" that can identify indexes in that list.

```
@{
  // declare counter
  int i = 0
}
@foreach (BuildingBlockField buildingBlockField in buildingBlockFields)
{
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="companyName">@buildingBlockField.FieldTitle</label>
       @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.buildingBlockFields[i].BuildingBlockFieldID)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[i].FieldTitle, new { @class = "form-control", Value = @buildingBlockField.FieldTitle })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.buildingBlockFields[i].Values, buildingBlockField.OptionDetails, "Select Contract", new { @class = "selectpicker", multiple = "multiple" })
     </div>

     @i++
}
```

Comment: Hello, i edited my code with your help it's working but do you know if there is an other way to do it or it's fine ? (I edited my answer)

Comment: Your current code looks better than my answer with the for loop. There's another way to do it without @Html helpers but it's just a different implementation and doesn't improve anything. Your current implementation is how I always do mine.

Comment: I understand how to do it know. Thank you very much for you help :)